# get random name from file in python

Tags: list, function, file, random, append

im a novice at python, i've wrote this those far it needs but i cant get it to run past line 4 the error is a syntax error def fileload filename what am i not doing correctly?

```
 import random


    def fileload(filename)
    with open(filename,"r") as names:
        for item in names:
        return item
```

collect lines from files and append to list

```
   def main():
        name=[]
        desc=[]
        title=[]

        filename=fileload(names.txt)
        for item in names:
            name.append(item)
            break

        filename=fileload(descriptors.txt)
        for item in description:
            desc.append(item)
            break

        filename=fileload(titles.txt)
        for item in titles:
            title.append(item)
```

random namer

```
        def namer():
        i=random.randint(0,len(names))
        first_name=names[i]
        last_name=names[i]

        return first_name last_name
```

random titler

```
    def titler():
    i= random.randint(0,len(title))
    random_title=title[i]
```

random description

```
         def descript():
        i=random.randint(0,len(desc))
        random_description = desc[i]
```

print out random names, titles and descriptor

```
print(f"you are; {random_title} {first_name} {last_name} the {random_title}")


    namer()
    titler()
    descript()
    main()
```

also some maybe out of my intended indentation blame the website for that

Comment: What is this supposed to accomplish?

Comment: The tabs and spaces are all mixed out. Can you fix it?

Comment: @scott hunter in main() i try to call def filename and it needs to read 3 different files which then gets added to a list so i can then pick out a random names title and description and i print that out in the last print line

Comment: @clavlav12 mixed out how?

Comment: Scroll up and watch yourself. I suggest pasting the whole code as one block... you can comment inside if you want